# Weighted Poincaré inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Consider a probability distribution $\pi$ with density $e^{-H(x)}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Let us say that there is a Poincaré inequality with weight $w$ if for any smooth function $\phi$ satisfying $\int \phi(x) \pi(dx) = 0$ the following inequality holds,
$$\int \phi'(x)^2 w^2(x) \pi(dx) \geq \int \phi(x)^2 \pi(dx).$$

**Question:**
given a positive function $h:\mathbb{R} \to (0;+\infty)$, can one compute the optimal weight function $w$ in the sense that $w$ minimizes $\int w^2(x) h^2(x) \pi(dx)$.

**Example:** if $\pi$ is a Gaussian measure ($i.e$ with $H(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^2$) and $h(x)=1$, playing around with Hermite polynomials, it does not seem very hard to check that $w(x)=\text{Cst}$ is optimal.

In the more general case, it seems like the optimal weight $w_0$ and associated test function $\phi_0$ defined by $\int \phi_0'(x)^2 w_0^2(x) \pi(dx) = \int \phi_0(x)^2 \pi(dx)$ must satisfy $\phi_0'(x)^2 = \lambda h^2(x)$ and $h$ is an eigenfunction of a certain differential operator involving $w_0$. I have not been able to explicitly find $w_0$ by continuing in this direction.

**Motivations:** given a metric on $\mathbb{R}$ ($i.e$ function $w^2$), one can consider the associated Langevin diffusion that has $\pi$ as invariant distribution. Among all the metric that satisfy certain conditions, which one maximizes the speed of convergence ($i.e$ spectral gap) of the Langevin diffusion towards $\pi$.

Comment: Hi,   
Alekk do you have any references about the "Spectral Gap" and speed of convergence analysis you are mentionning in your motivations ? Regards

Comment: the easiest way to understand these concepts might be to first see what is happening in a discrete setting: the book "Markov Chains and Mixing Times" by Levin, Peres, Wilmer is a beautiful introduction to these subjects.

Comment: @Alekk. I'm wondering about your function $h$. What are the typical $h$'s you have in mind? What would be the meaning of $h$ for the Langevin diffusion you mentioned in "Motivations"? Is the $h$ in the paragraph between Example and Motivations the same $h$ of the Question? Could you say a bit more on this?     

Answer (score 1):

For various inequalities of this kind see also

S. G. Bobkov and M. Ledoux, Weighted Poincaré-type inequalities for Cauchy and other convex measures.  Ann. Probab. 37, No. 2, 403-427 (2009). ArXiv: 0906.1651.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, you can do better for the gaussian measure : you an choose $w(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Maybe you can be interested in Gozlan's work :

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aihp/1281100396

and one of mine

https://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/ktanguy/files/2012/04/euclid.ejp_.1550653272.pdf